# MYSQL group and order query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with name and order date. I am trying to come up with a query to show the last time each name ordered in reverse order. So each names newest order but sorted by the name that ordered earliest.

So with this data

```
Tom,10/01/2013  
Bob,09/24/2013  
Tom,11/03/2013  
Tom,10/24/2013  
Bill,11/01/2013  
Bob,10/22/2013
```

I want this

```
Bob,10/22/2013  
Bill,11/01/2013  
Tom,11/03/2013
```

I have tried `SELECT * from orders group by name order by -odate`
that got either random or older than the newest dates
I then tried `SELECT * from orders order by -odate group by name`
thinking it would sort first but it returned nothing

Thanks
Ed

Comment: SELECT * from orders group by name order by -odate DESC

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, MAX(odate) odate FROM orders GROUP BY name ORDER BY odate
```

Comment: didn't work. It set all dates to 01/01/1970. odate is a datetime field

Comment: @PaulDraper It works fine in the fiddle in Richard Harrison's answer. You must be doing something wrong that's zeroing out the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MAX` function for your date column

```
SELECT name, MAX(odate) from orders group by name order by odate
```

Comment: You forgot the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Barmar: When I use the `MAX` function, is there any point to use `order by`?

Comment: `MAX` just picks a particular value for each group, but it doesn't order the groups in the final results.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks ... I forgot that :)

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is to GROUP BY the name, but to select the maximum value that you need.

When grouping you can perform range functions on other fields.

Using the ORDER BY  DESC puts the most recent first.

```
SELECT name, MAX(odate) AS odate FROM orders GROUP BY name ORDER BY odate DESC
```

see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a57d/1)

Comment: Why are you using `DESC` when he wants them in forward order, not reverse?

Comment: Thanks! Can't bump you up as I don't have a high enough rating.

Comment: Richard was right about the order. I mistakenly had the - in there

Comment: @Barmar based on the text of the question rather than the example